# Tomcat 8, HikariCP, Hibernate and MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, tomcat, hikaricp

## Using a Connection Pool

I am using a Hikari Connection Pool to interact with the MySQl database backend in a Java based Web project. I decided to upgrade the library versions to their most recent stable versions and now I cannot connect to the database anymore.

- Java 8
- MySQL 5.7
- Tomcat 8

## Dependencies

I use the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

## Hibernate

The project compiles fine, no libraries are missing. This is my hibernate configuration file:

```
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CitationUserDB?useSSL=false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">dbUser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">vErYsEcReT</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>

    <mapping class="Database.Authentication.User"/>

</session-factory>
```

## SessionFactory

I use this Hibernate Util class to get the session object.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

/**
 * Hibernate session management
 */
public class HibernateUtilUserAuthentication {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.userauthentication.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                    = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

## Error

The following error is thrown, when the first database access happens in the source code. There seems to be a problem with the claspath, but all required libraries are there and I can see them in IntelliJ.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at Database.Authentication.HibernateUtilUserAuthentication.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtilUserAuthentication.java:104)
    at Database.Authentication.UserAPI.authenticateUser(UserAPI.java:133)
    at Database.Authentication.UserAuthentication.login(UserAuthentication.java:60)
    at Bean.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.configure(HikariConnectionProvider.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:120)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolUtilities.initializeDataSource(PoolUtilities.java:110)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:157)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.configure(HikariConnectionProvider.java:82)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:105)
    ... 70 more
```

But the library is there:
[image]

It is copied to Tomcat during deployment:

```
./webapps/Testapplication/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-6.0.2.jar
```

I have no idea why the JDBC MySQL driver cannot be found. Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package structure has changed in mysql-connector-java-6. Switch to mysql-connector-java-5.x

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello, I already tried revertig back to the previous version of the MySQL connector, but I still receive the same error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"

Comment: @MightyApe You have also redeployed your app after changing?

Comment: Yes, of course, I use the tomcat7-maven-plugin for deployment.

Comment: I have to add an correction. when I tested if the older 5.1.39 version would work, I did not change the version in all the modules. My current project uses different individual modules, each having a separated pom file. So there was in a different module still a MySQL 6.0.2 dependency. Changing all of them back works! The documentation of the  MySQL 6.0.2 connector states that  this would be the new path for the packe, but this class is not existing: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Is this because the version is still in development?